# Нужно определить среднее значение. Выдает ошибку "Программа выводит ответ в неверном формате"

Tags: c++

Условие задачи:
Определите среднее значение всех элементов последовательности, завершающейся числом 0. Сам ноль в последовательность не входит.
Использовать массивы в данной задаче нельзя.

Входные данные:
Вводится последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся числом 0 (само число 0 в последовательность не входит, а служит как признак её окончания.

Мой код:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float sa = 0.0;
    float count = 0.0;
    float summa = 0.0;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    while (x > 0) {
        summa += x;
        count++;
        cin >> x;
    }
    if (x == 0) {
        sa = summa / count;
        cout << sa;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Может, в условии что-то сказано о формате? И еще - где-то сказано, что последовательность *именно целых* чисел? Такие вопросы лучше задавать вместе с URL, чтобы это был точный текст задания, а не его трактовка вами...

Comment: это и есть точный текст задания

Comment: Переведите строку после ответа. Всё заработает.

Comment: `while (x > 0)` -> `while (x != 0)`.

Comment: я использовал float, т.к у меня с int была такая же ошибка, и я посчитал, что проблема в том, что int нельзя делить так, чтобы в ответе была плавающая точка

Comment: `float` -> `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из условия следует, что задана последовательность целых чисел, а данный код обрабатывает только положительные. Если в псоледовательности есть отрицательное число программа ничего не выведет, оттого и ошибка в формате вывода.